How To Parse a XML Column with string data type into multiple sql columns In Databricks
I have a table with XML data in it which is stored in a column with STRING datatype.
Can someone please help me on how to parse this XML into multiple sql columns.
Below is the sample XML Table & desired output data.
Select * from default.SampleData

XMLData:
'Status': {
        'Code': 'Ok',
        'Message': None,
        'Errors': None
    },
    'RequestReference': None,
    'Response': {
        'IdNumber': '295',
        'SearchKeys': {
            'Subject': {
                'FirstName': 'John',
                'MiddleName': None,
                'Surname': 'Ross',
                'DateOfBirth': datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 31, 0, 0),
                'Gender': 'M'
            },
            'Address': {
                'AddressLine1': '123 old street',
                'AddressLine2': 'high street',
                'AddressLine3': '',
                'AddressLine4': None,
                'AddressLine5': None,
                'Postcode': '12345',
                'Country': None
            },
            'Phone': None,
            'DrivingLicence': None,
            'Bank': None,
            'ConsentFlag': True
        },

Expected output columns
IDNumber   FirstName   MiddleName   LastName  DateOfBirth  AddressLine1     Phone 
295        John                      Ross      1900-01-01   123 Highstreet   Nonedatab


Could you please provide your approach, if you have tried anything?

i tried the below code and getting an error, FYI My actual table name is different from sample above

%python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
Directly use the DataFrame returned by the SQL query
df = spark.sql("select response from default.idcheck")
df = df.repartition(100)
Extract the idchecknumber using xpath_string
id = F.expr('xpath_string(response, "IdNumber/text()")')
Add the idchecknumber as a new column
df = df.withColumn('id', id)
Select the id column
df = df.select('id')
Display the DataFrame
display(df)

Provide valid data, the data you have provided is not in correct format?

You mention XML but this looks like Python dict?!

this seems like json data. use from_json function instead of xpath

Check below answer. @JohnBryan

Your data seems to be json and not the xml but here is the code for both the ways.
For parsing xml data your xml string should be something like below.
'<a><b>b</b><c>cc</c></a>'

and parse it like below.
df.withColumn("parse_XMLData", xpath_string(col("XMLData"), lit("a/c"))).display()

Output:
| XMLData                  | parse_XMLData |
|--------------------------|---------------|
| <a><b>b</b><c>cc</c></a> | cc            |

xpath_string give first xml node which matches the expression.
Similarly you give like below.
df.withColumn("parse_XMLData", xpath_string(col("XMLData"), lit("IdNumber"))).display()

If you want all the node matching the expression you use xpath function which returns array of strings matched the given expression.
Next, if it is the json data you use from_json function  like mentioned here.
